# What are the probabilities for more than +/- 3 standard deviations away from the mean in a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

With a normal distribution, I'm familiar with +/- 1, 2, and 3 standard deviations:

+/-

1: 68%

2: 95.45%

3: 99.73%

What are the probabilities for +/- 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or even 10 standard deviations away from the mean?

Comment: For large arguments, note that the upper tail probability, $1-\Phi(z)\approx \phi(z)/z \approx \frac{0.3989}{z}e^{-\frac12 z^2}$ and the probability in both tails is then $\approx \frac{0.7979}{z} e^{-\frac12 z^2}$. e.g. for $z=10$ (10 s.d.'s) this gives  $1.53892\times 10^{-23}$ while the exact answer is $1.52397... \times 10^{-23}$. The larger the number of standard deviations, the better this works.

Answer (score 2):

We can figure this out by using the *cumulative density function* of the normal distribution.

In math notation, $\Psi(n)-\Psi(-n)$, where $\Psi$ is the cdf and $n$ the number of standard deviations.

In R for example:

```
(pnorm(1:10)-pnorm(-(1:10)))
```

0.6826895 0.9544997 0.9973002 0.9999367 0.9999994 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000

As we can see, it goes to 1 very quickly (though never quite reaches it; we observe exactly 1 due to numerical error).

Comment: You can also use log=TRUE in pnorm to allow for higher-precision reporting of the probability, to give a better view of just how close to 1 the probability gets.

Comment: yeah but you have to be careful about how you do the computation because it's the log of a *difference*; it's not as simple as just doing log=TRUE in this case (we need to do the logsumexp trick).

Comment: It doesn't have to be expressed as a difference because the distribution is symmetric.  `10^(pnorm(-(1:10), log = TRUE)/log(10) + log10(2))` does the trick for the common logarithms* of the complementary* probabilities. Thus, for instance, because the last value output is `1.523971e-23`, we deduce your last "1.0000000" really is $0.9999999999999999999998476029...$

Comment: nice moves @whuber. I bet you rocked intro stats ;)

Comment: I never took an intro stats course ;-).